# Spyder: Check failed: PyBfloat16_Type.tp_base != nullptr error while starting kernel

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda, spyder

I am getting some weird error when starting Spyder 3.6.  The error reads:

```
An error ocurred while starting the kernel
2018 15:37:39.970424: F T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\python\lib\core\bfloat16.cc:664]
Check failed: PyBfloat16_Type.tp_base != nullptr
```

I Googled for a solution and found this:

```
conda update setuptools
```

I ran that in the Anaconda console; still dealing with the same issue.  This has been working fine for more than 1 year, and I don't know what changed in the past day or so.  The only thing that I have done recently is run Jupyter Notebook; I tried a few sample scripts in that environment and everything ran fine.  I can't think of anything that has changed in the past 1-2 days.  Any idea what could be wrong here?  Thanks!

Comment: After a hard reboot on my Windows 7 machine it seems like everything is back to normal now.

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
conda install tensorflow
```

This will solve the problem